# setTimeout(function() is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am currently working to create a custom alert box for any errors and below is the code I am using, the alert box is appearing fine but it's not auto-closing after 600 milliseconds, its only closed after the manual click of the close button. what I am doing wrong here and how to auto-disappear the alert box

Comment: " it's not auto-closing after 600 minutes"...you mean milliseconds. right? setTimeout accepts values in miliseconds

Comment: "its only closed after the manual click of the close button"...because you placed the setTimeout command inside a "click" event handler i.e. `close[i].onclick=`, so the function which contains the timeout code is only executed when the user clicks on it. If you want it to be automatic then simply don't put it in an event handler. It seems maybe you don't really understand some of the basic syntax of the code you've written.

Comment: @ADyson- Yes its 600 milliseconds, Sorry for the typo

Comment: No problem...now, more importantly, do you understand my second comment? Incidentally if you auto-hide after 600 milliseconds that's 0.6 seconds, the user will barely have time to notice the box, never mind read the information

Comment: You could do $('#closebtn').trigger('click').  Have you logged the div variable to see which parent element is being returned. You have 2 divs with class alet on them.

Comment: @JeanB there's no jQuery included in this page. Stick to vanilla JS syntax. Anyway why trigger a click when a timeout could simply be declared outside the click handler? Seems like an unnecessary layer of indirection

Comment: @ADyson - Thanks for the explanation, Understood your second command and corrected the errors in the javascript.Its working and change the auto-hide value as well...

Comment: If you've changed something but still have a problem, you'll have to edit the question and show us what the code looks like now, and give a clearer explanation of what is happening. "not working" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Sorry, I want to update its working...typo in my comment again.

Comment: The div is not closed because you set the timeout inside the close event of the div

Comment: @SimbuStar That's great, glad you fixed it. In that case you should make an Answer with the working version of the code, so that others with a similar issue can understand it in future. You are allowed to "accept" your own answer, and also it gives others the opportunity to upvote it, which of course gets you extra reputation... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I moved the setTimeout outside the click event and set the div value:

```js
function displayError(errorMessage) {
    var messageObject = "<div class='alert' id='alertbox'><span class='closebtn' id='closebtn'>&times;</span><strong><font color='#f44336;'>Error!</font></strong>"+errorMessage+"</div>"
    document.getElementById("divMessageContainer").innerHTML += messageObject;
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        var div = close[i].parentElement;
        setTimeout(function(){div.style.display = "none"; }, 600);
        close[i].onclick = function(){            
            div.style.opacity = "0";            
        }
    }
}
```

```css
div#alertbox{padding: 10px;bottom: 40px;left: 5px; max-width: 800px; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;z-index: 99; max-width: 700px; color: #000;background-color: #EEE;border-radius: 10px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 10px;}
span#closebtn {margin-left: 15px;color: black;font-weight: bold;float: right;font-size: 22px;line-height: 20px; cursor: pointer; transition: 0.3s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="divMessageContainer"></div>
<button onclick="displayError()">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the below steps and fixed the issue reported here, The below approach allowed me to show multiple alert box at the same time and auto close them based on the message number instead of close all the alert box at the same time

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
div.alertbox{padding: 10px;bottom: 40px;left: 5px; max-width: 800px; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;z-index: 99; max-width: 700px; color: #000;background-color: #EEE;border-radius: 10px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 10px;}
span#closebtn {margin-left: 15px;color: black;font-weight: bold;float: right;font-size: 22px;line-height: 20px; cursor: pointer; transition: 0.3s;}
</style>
<body>
<div id="divMessageContainer"></div>
<button onclick="displayError()">button</button>
</body>
<script>
var messageCount = 0;
var messageTimeout = 3000;
function displayError(errorMessage) {
    var messageObject = "<div class='alertbox' id='alertbox"+messageCount+"'><span class='closebtn' id='closebtn'>&times;</span><strong><font color='#f44336;'>Error!</font></strong>"+errorMessage+"</div>"
    document.getElementById("divMessageContainer").innerHTML += messageObject;
    var messageID = messageCount;
    setTimeout(function(){removeElement("alertbox" + messageID); }, messageTimeout);
    closeAlertbox();    
}

function removeElement(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id)) {      
        return (elem=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);     
    }
}


function closeAlertbox() {
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function(){
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.opacity = "0";
            setTimeout(function()
            { div.style.display = "none"; 
            }, 10);
        }
    }
} 
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `remove()` to remove the alertbox, so there won't be any closebuttons left and the `for`-loop can be removed.

Maybe this would be a possible solution:

```js
function displayError(errorMessage) {
  var messageObject = "<div id='moo' class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert' auto-close='2000'><div class='alert' id='alertbox'><span class='closebtn' id='closebtn'>&times;</span><strong><font color='#f44336;'>Error!</font></strong>"+errorMessage+"</div>";
  var container = document.getElementById("divMessageContainer");
  container.innerHTML += messageObject;
  var box = document.getElementById("alertbox");
  var close = document.querySelector(".closebtn");
  close.onclick = function(){
    box.remove();
  };
  setTimeout(function(){
    box.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      box.remove();
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
div#alertbox{padding: 10px;bottom: 40px;left: 5px; max-width: 800px; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;z-index: 99; max-width: 700px; color: #000;background-color: #EEE;border-radius: 10px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 10px; -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;}
span#closebtn {margin-left: 15px;color: black;font-weight: bold;float: right;font-size: 22px;line-height: 20px; cursor: pointer; transition: 0.3s;}
```

```html
<div id="divMessageContainer"></div>
<button onclick="displayError()">button</button>
```

I also added a `transition` to `opacity`, so if the user doesn't manually close the alertbox, it will fade (in this case after 2 seconds, but you can play with that time).

Answer (score -1):

```js
function displayError(errorMessage) {
    var messageObject = "<div id='moo' class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert' auto-close='2000'><div class='alert' id='alertbox'><span class='closebtn' id='closebtn'>&times;</span><strong><font color='#f44336;'>Error!</font></strong>"+errorMessage+"</div>"
    document.getElementById("divMessageContainer").innerHTML += messageObject;
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
    var i, index;
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){
         close[index].parentElement.style.display = "none";
            index++;
        }, 600);
        close[i].onclick = function(){
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Try this one. Take care about loop when using async.

Comment: why have you got a separate `index` variable?